# Symfony function available in all models

Tags: php, function, symfony1, symfony-1.4, global

I want to use a function in all models class (in project folder and in plugins folder).

Where should I declare it?

Comment: Possible, that you asked this question already today? http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html

Comment: Helper function or actual behavior of entity classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what your function does, you can create a file in the `lib` folder and then call it from every where in your app. This is useful in a Symfony project to define common functions (like a toolbox).

For example, in [the Jobeet tutorial](http://svn.jobeet.org/trunk/lib/Jobeet.class.php), they define a method called `slugify` in `/lib/Jobeet.class.php` *(be sure to name the file with `.class.php` at the end so Symfony will automatically load it)*. Then, you can call `Jobeet::slugify()` every where in your app/model/plugin/view.

Answer (score -4):

This solution works with Symfony 1.4:

- You create a new file in which you declare the function you want to be available everywhere.
- You load that file with the [auto prepend file setting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file)in the php.ini file.

If done correctly, that function is available in all your scripts, regardless of model, plugin or something else from your project.

Comment: Best to use `auto_prepend_file` per directory. Otherwise it will be included for all sites that use the `php.ini`. Regardless, not sure if creating an external dependency like this is the way to go. Symfony 1.4 has a `/lib` directory.

Comment: -1 Yeah, I have to agree with @webbiedave's last sentence here.  Using a php.ini setting for this would be *extremely* unexpected for any developer who wasn't intimately familiar with the project, especially when Symfony already provides a mechanism to accomplish it.

Comment: @Phoenix: If it works, it works. Not saying this is the best answer, but technically it's correct. Per directory settings are available per php.ini - see user ini.